# What is the numerical difference in the number of files in two different directories for every sequence (seq 1-current)?

Tags: bash

Every time I write a new amount of data, two new directories are created called a sequence.
Directory 1 should always be 9 files larger than Directory 2.

I’m using ls | wc –l to output the number of files in each directory then manually doing the difference.
For example

Sequence 151

Directory 1 /raid2/xxx/xxxx/NHY274938WSP1151-OnlineSEHD-hyp  (1911 files) – after WSP1 is the seq number.

Directory 2 - /raid/xxx/ProjectNumber/xxxx/seq0151           (1902 files)

Sequence 152

Directory 1 /raid2/xxx/xxxx/NHY274938WSP1152-OnlineSEHD-hyp         (1525 files)

Directory 2 - /raid/xxx/ProjectNumber/xxxx/seq0152                  (1516 files)

Is there a script that will output the difference (minus 9) for every sequence.
Ie
151 diff= 0
152 diff =0

---

That works great however:
I can now see some sequences in
Directory 1 (RAW/all files) it contains extra files that i dont want compared against diectory 2 these are:

At the beginning Warmup files (not set amount every sequence)

Duplicate files with an _

For example :

20329.uutt -warmup

20328.uutt  -warmup

.

.

21530.uutt First good file after warmup

.

.

19822.uutt

19821.uutt

19820.uutt

19821_1.uutt

Directory 2 (reprocessed /missing files) doesn’t include warmup shots or Duplicate files with an _

For example :

Missing shots

*021386 – first available file (files are missing before).

*021385

.

.

*019822

*019821

*019820

Could we remove warmup files and any duplicates I should have number of missing files?
Or output
diff, D1#warmup files, D1#duplicate files, TOTdiff

to get D1#duplicate files maybe I could count the total number of occurances of *_*.uutt

to get D1#warmup files I have a log file where warmup shots have a "WARM" at the end of each line. in /raid2/xxx/xxxx/NHY274938WSP1151.log

i.e.

"01/27/21 15:33:51 :FLD211018WSP1004: SP:21597: SRC:2: Shots:1037: Manifold:2020:000 Vol:4000:828 Spread: 1.0:000 FF:  nan:PtP: 0.000:000 WARM"

"01/27/21 15:34:04 :FLD211018WSP1004: SP:21596: SRC:4: Shots:1038: Manifold:2025:000 Vol:4000:000 Spread: 0.2:000 FF:  nan:PtP: 0.000:000 WARM"

Comment: @Ali Stokes - Shall the script operate on the fixed paths, or do you want to call it with arguments, and if the latter, which?

Comment: An argument like specifying just a single sequence for example? An argument might be great later on but what you have written works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a script that will output the difference (minus 9) for every sequence. Ie 151 diff= 0 152 diff =0

There it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
d1p=/raid2/xxx/xxxx/NHY274938WSP1   # Directory 1 prefix
d1s=-OnlineSEHD-hyp                 # Directory 1 suffix
d2=/raid/xxx/ProjectNumber/xxxx/seq0
for d in $d2*
do  s=${d: -3}                      # extract sequence from Directory 2
    echo $s diff=$(expr `ls $d1p$s$d1s|wc -l` - `ls $d|wc -l` - 9)
done
```

With filename expansion [`*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) we get all the directory names, and by removing the fixed part with the parameter expansion [`${parameter:offset}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) we get the sequence.

For comparison here's a variant using arrays as suggested by tripleee:

```
#!/bin/bash
d1p=/raid2/xxx/xxxx/NHY274938WSP1   # Directory 1 prefix
d1s=-OnlineSEHD-hyp                 # Directory 1 suffix
d2=/raid/xxx/ProjectNumber/xxxx/seq0
shopt -s nullglob                   # make it work also for 0 files
for d in $d2*
do  s=${d: -3}                      # extract sequence from Directory 2
    f1=($d1p$s$d1s/*)               # expand files from Directory 1
    f2=($d/*)                       # expand files from Directory 2
    echo $s diff=$((${#f1[@]} - ${#f2[@]} - 9))
done
```

Comment: Probably [don't use `ls` in scripts.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Counting the number of lines is incorrect if the file names contain newlines (though arguably this is a corner case anyway). Using arrays instead would be less brittle anyway, and also simplify the code considerably.

Comment: Do you care to prove your claim that _Using arrays_ _would_ _simplify the code considerably_?

Comment: Not near my computer, but using `expr` in a Bash script is always a bad smell. Briefly, if you have the files in the arrays `d1` and `d2`, `$(( ${#d1[@]} - ${#d2[@]} - 9))` produces the desired result by way of an arithmetic expression, without the use of any external processes.